# Is there any needs to install anything to run another page(except index.php) in laravel framework. Except npm, model, controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

i've tried a project and can't connect another page in laravel. there is an error of (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.)

Comment: it's because of error in routing.

Answer (score 0):

1.check route that you mention right controller name
2.check the file path which you want to access.
3.check it does exists for laravel or not

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much friends who are responding me, and there was an error in installing the npm. it was done successfully but there was some warnings which i missed to consider, anyways it's working properly